# Migrating from mui v4 to v5 | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyboardDate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

Hello after updating the MUI v4 to version v5 i got faling test's that's looking like this

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyboardDate')

      17 |   it("should render correctly without any errors", () => {
      18 |     expect(
    > 19 |       renderer.create(<DatePickerElement onChange={onChange} value="10/08/1981" />).toJSON(),
         |                ^
      20 |     ).toMatchSnapshot();
      21 |   });
      22 |   // props testing
```

I've done i think everything according to the guide migration and can't think of reason why this faling the component is wrapped with new `<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} utils={DateFnsUtils}>` and working fine only the test's are faling at render method did any one encountred similiar issue?

```
it("should render correctly without any errors", () => {
expect(
  renderer
    .create(<DatePickerElement onChange={onChange} value="10/08/1981" />)
    .toJSON(),
).toMatchSnapshot();  });
```

Comment: Did you try to upgrade (or downgrade) your testing library ?

Comment: @nboyet yep tried i think almost everything even lifting the react version and upgrading the deps to lastest version's

Comment: @nboyet i found the issue the problem was the mui v5 itself i mean by that the old version's it's kinda strange since i installed it like week or two ago. So overall newest versions fixes that problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the new migration, some Datepicker dependencies seem to be unstable or incompatible, and I find the official mui documentation doesn't do a good job of specifying compatible versions. Still, [these docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/pickers-migration/) provide additional info about the pickers migration from @material-ui to @mui.

I ran into the undefined keyboardDate issue and solved it by installing these specific versions of dependencies:

Dependencies I used:

```
"@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
"@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
"date-fns": "^2.23.0",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.10",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.112",
```

Imports:
Please remember to import LocalizationProvider, AdapterDateFns, DatePicker from `@mui/x-date-pickers`, as @mui/lab v5 moved their locations.

Snippet:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} utils={MomentUtils}>
  <DatePicker 
    label='Start Date'
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    inputFormat="mm/dd/yyyy"
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```